How can I present two different themed login pages with django-allauth
I am using django-allauth successfully in a project.
What I would like to do is have another set of login/create account pages, but themed differently.  However the template_names of the views are fixed by the allauth view.
e.g:
class LoginView(
    RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView
):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "account/login." + app_settings.TEMPLATE_EXTENSION

In the above, the template_name is fixed.
I've considered adding a URL query parameter to influence the template rendering, but query paramters are not kept across redirections, nor the generated urls that are set during get_context_data().   So if I started on a login page of theme A, and decided to create an account instead, I'd end up on a non-A-themed 'create account page' (because that URL, to the create-account page, would not include my query parameter)
So the 'query parameter' idea seems like it would be a very brittle approach.
Is there a way I can achieve this? (btw: it's Django 3.x, not the latest).

There might be a nicer way, but for now what I've done:

Override the existing class based views, and specified new a template_name for each.
Add new templates (copied from the existing), modifying style to suit.
Add a set of specialized urls in urls.py, that match the new themed login pages.

So this isn't ideal (especially the duplication of the templates).  But I couldn't think of another way to go about it.
There are also cases within the new views where I have to override get_context_data and more or less repeat the reverse() lookups, just so I can point to a new URL, e.g
class AppsumoPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'account/appsumo/password_reset.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        login_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(
            self.request, reverse("appsumo_account_login"), self.redirect_field_name
        )
        context['login_url'] = login_url
        return context


The only real change above is the use of appsumo_account_login in reverse().
So there's a bunch of similar small modifications like this, to all the views.
So. It works. Not great (I think).
